# "connection is not secure" error on xampp local host

Tags: firefox, web, xampp, localhost

Firefox started suddenly redirecting all my local host websites to https. Then it shows this error without any option to bypass it:
[image: Firefox error message]

I didn't change anything in XAMPP.

I tried to clear history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resulted from using .dev for local domains.

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: Well that's a new one, didn't ever had any issues with the silly xampp :)